# mdframed: how to prevent a box from splitting?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I would like to prevent an `mdframed` box to split.

I know it could sound absurd, since `mdframed` is designed to allow splitting but if it could be done, I would be interested in modifying `mdframed` so that I can decide whenever I want to split or not.

Does anyone has a clue on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `nobreak` key to prevent a box from splitting:

```
\begin{mdframed}[nobreak=true]
contents
\end{mdframed}
```